# R warnings "IMKClient Stall detected"

Tags: r, macos, macos-sierra

I am receiving the following warnings in R since I upgraded to a new MBP. The warnings appear when I start the app and reappear at odd intervals.

> 2016-12-06 15:05:02.067 R[87426:4480089] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (59.22 secs).
>
> 2016-12-06 15:05:02.068 R[87426:4480089] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (53.97 secs).
>
> 2016-12-06 15:05:02.069 R[87426:4480089] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (51.94 secs).
>
> 2016-12-06 15:05:02.070 R[87426:4480089] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (47.89 secs).
>
> 2016-12-06 15:05:02.070 R[87426:4480089] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (43.12 secs).
>
> 2016-12-06 15:05:02.071 R[87426:4480089] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (37.01 secs).
>
> 2016-12-06 15:05:02.072 R[87426:4480089] IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem - (imkxpc_presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:reply:) block performed very slowly (8.31 secs).
>
> 2016-12-06 15:11:32.969 R[87426:4480089] IMKInputSession presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler: : *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process.}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem

The output of `sessionInfo()`

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
    Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.1

    locale:
    [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_3.3.2
```

There seems to be virtually no info on this other than [this unanswered threat](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Anybody-know-the-cause-of-this-td4722403.html). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have this error when running my own code. it appears when i run some auto generated applescript and then execute it. i suspect that this occurs when the interface of whatever program you use at the time freezes, probably because the developer hasn't written the background processes of the program in question to work on another thread.

as far as i can tell with this it doesn't seem to actively break anything, so i'd just ignore it. if you're really bothered by it you could run an update of your most used programs and see if it's been fixed.